# how can we click on custom add-ins in excel through sikuli?

Tags: selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRMaB.png)i have a excel, in that we have "add-ins" tool bar in that we have some add-ins to perform some actions. (like refresh the excel, submit the job to DB etc.,)

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your window size normalized. Use:

```
click(location) # where location is one of the choices next to region, location, offset ...
```